# Word Interop- Add new autotext/building block

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

I need to update a bunch of values that are currently stored in multiple word documents as Auto Text (or Building Blocks), there are too many to do by hand so I was hoping to use the Interop Word API.

```
var app = new Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Open(@"c:\path\to\file.dot");
```

Unfortunately I cannot see any members of `Document` related to the Auto Text feature in Word (Insert > Quick Parts > Building Blocks Organizer).

Does the API expose any way of adding/updating Auto Text values in the  'Building Blocks Organizer'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a new document and attach the template to that document, from the top of my head:

ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = @"C:\path\to\file.dot";

After that you can interate over the AutoTextEntries like this (a VBA Example, but I'm sure you can rewrite it to C# quickly by yourself)

```
Sub test()

    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = @"C:\path\to\file.dot"

    For Each oAutoText In ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries
        MsgBox oAutoText.Value
        oAutoText.Value = Replace(oAutoText.Value, strOld, strNew)
    Next oAutoText

End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks. Unfortunately the documents I am working with have been misused meaning I can’t actually update the AutoText programmatically but do have a working version.